# Photo Gallery Software

Tags: image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-hosted image gallery](https://superuser.com/questions/1378/self-hosted-image-gallery)

I need a recommendation for photo gallery software to run on my server.  It needs to be light and fast.  Coppermine and gallery are to heavy and slow.  I have also tried Qdig and it is nearly perfect, but its very very slow and takes a lot of resources.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1378/self-hosted-image-gallery

Comment: Not really an exact dupe, just a better title needed. He's looking for a lightweight solution, those don't really fit the bill, especially with the one he doesn't want (gallery) being the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Zenphoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/) is one of the better minimalistic web galleries I'm aware of. It is **very** light on resources and simple to use. Feel free to check out the [live demo](http://www.zenphoto.org/zenphoto/)!

> **The simplest, most useful web gallery software!**
>
> Zenphoto is a gallery CMS that just
>   makes sense and doesn’t try to do
>   everything and your dishes. We hope
>   you agree with our philosophy: **simpler
>   is better**. Don’t get us wrong though –
>   Zenphoto really does have everything
>   you need for web media gallery
>   management.

[image]

Comment: this would fit on the duplicate, too; maybe repost there.